# make clarity design buttongroup responsive

Tags: css, button, responsive, vmware-clarity, buttongroup

How to make clarity design button group responsive like clarity button ?

this is the actual behavior of clarity button group :

[image: this is the actual behavior of clarity button group :]

and here the behavior of the normal clarity button :

[image: behavior of the normal clarity button]

As you can see width of button are reduced and text-overflow is ellipsis.

How can i add the same properties to button group ?

my dependency :

```
"@angular/animations": "^9.0.5",
"@angular/common": "^9.0.5",
"@angular/compiler": "^9.0.5",
"@angular/core": "^9.0.5",
"@angular/forms": "^9.0.5",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^9.0.5",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.0.5",
"@angular/router": "^9.0.5",
"@clr/angular": "^2.3.8",
"@clr/icons": "^2.3.8",
"@clr/ui": "^2.3.8",
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found a solution

put this css rules to button group

```
.btn-group {
  display: flex;
}
```

and to your label

```
label {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

this should be the normal behavior, but anyway this work

Comment: The reason we don't do this is because hidden text like this is an accessibility violation. Users should be able to see all of the content in an element to properly access the options, especially in an interactive element like a button.